# Reading MySQL data into highstocks

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, highcharts

So this is the first time i have really worked with high charts i have some data reading into high charts from my MySQL database, but the next step is to try and set up a high stocks chart. Whenever i try and use the same method as i did with high charts the chart doesn't work? This is what i want to aim for - [StockChartDemo](https://www.highcharts.com/stock/demo/column)

PHP Code:

```
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbName);

if ($conn->connect_error) {
die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$sql = "(SELECT date AS time ,IFNULL(RH,'null')AS humidity
            FROM test ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 20) ORDER BY time ASC";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows>0){
$count =0;
echo '[';
while($row=$result->fetch_assoc()){      
  echo '['.$row["time"].',' .$row["humidity"].']';
  $count++;
   if ($count<"20"){
   echo ',';
   }      
 }
 echo ']';
}else{
echo "[[],[]]";
}
$conn->close();
?>
```

html & jQuery:

```
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="highstock.js"></script>

</head>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {
Highcharts.setOptions({
global: {
        useUTC: false
        }
});
var options = {    
    chart: {
        renderTo: 'tempcontainer',
        alignTicks: false,
          height:320,

    },

    rangeSelector: {
        selected: 1
    },

    title: {
        text: 'Relative humidity'
    },

    series: [{
        type: 'column',
        name: 'Humidity',
        data: json,
        dataGrouping: {
            units: [[
                'month', // unit name
                [1] // allowed multiples
            ], [
                'week',
                [1, 2, 3, 4, 6]
            ]]
        }
    }]


}

$.getJSON("stockdata.php", function(json) {    /*Get the array data in data.php using jquery getJSON function*/
    options.series[0].data = json;        /*assign the array variable to chart data object*/
    chart = new Highcharts.stockChart(options); /*create a new chart*/
});

function refreshChart(){                 /*function is called every set interval to refresh(recreate the chart) with the new data from data.php*/
    setInterval(function(){
        $.getJSON("stockdata.php", function(json) {
            options.series[0].data = json;
            chart = new Highcharts.stockChart(options);
        });
    },60000);
}
});

</script>
   <div id="tempcontainer"></div>
```

Comment: Really you should be using `json_encode()` instead of building your json manually as its going to cause `,]` which is invalid.

Comment: I definitely thought about it, considering the data in the database has been decoded and inserted raw anyway. Can you provide a manual or some articles on how i could go about completing this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presuming your query is returning the correct data you want. (I'm not up for mocking it out to test your query)

You should switch out the following code, and all that in-between.

```
if ($result->num_rows>0){
 //snip
}
```

To use [`json_encode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) instead.

```
$series = [];
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {  
        $series[] = [
            $row["time"],
            $row["humidity"]
        ];
    }
}

header('Content-Type: application/json');
exit(json_encode($series));
```

Comment: Untested, though you can see how it reduces your lines

Comment: I implemented it all in to my current code which doesn't work at the moment? I think it may have something to do with the JavaScript part of the code.

Comment: Could you provide us with a content of the `json` object? Also, instead of creating a new chart every 60 seconds, you can use `setData` (http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/Series.setData) or `update` (http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/Series.update) functions to update the data of the existing one.

Comment: Sure, so the output looks like this - time,data - [[1708-01-17 00,13],[1708-01-17 00,13],[1708-01-17 00,13],[1708-01-17 00,13],

Comment: @LawrenceCherone Tested out your code again and works thanks mate!

Comment: @hokletrain np, dont forget to upvote if it helped :)

Comment: @LawrenceCherone I just cant display the data into the chart now :/ Output works fine though - [["1708-01-17 00:00:00","13"],["1708-01-17 00:00:00","13"],["1708-01-17 00:","13"]

Comment: If you look at them numbers output is not right, year 1708? and the time is off on some `00:`, the date should be in microtime format eg: `1331028000000` if you check your browser's console log you may see javascript notices also.

Comment: Never mind guys, fixed it all! @LawrenceCherone all i did was add " JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK" at the end of the json_encode which formatted it to a value/int. To provide this ["1708-01-17 00:00:00",13] instead of this ["1708-01-17 00:00:00","13"].. Thanks for the help guys.